# PHP if statement dependent on value

Tags: php, if-statement

We currently have the following code which displays a link if a quotation is viewable:

```
        <td><?php echo $this->__($_quotation->getstatus()); ?></td>
        <td class="a-center">
            <?php if ($_quotation->isViewableByCustomer()): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getViewUrl($_quotation) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Quotation') ?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
```

We're looking to show the link if the quotation status value equals **Active** or **Expired** but not **Pending**.

How should I change this code around to reflect this?

Comment: what is in the `$_quotation` function?

Comment: Post the code from the `isViewableByCustomer()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you intend to show the status cell in any condition, and only link to it if Active or Expired. at least that's how I read your question.

Assuming the function `$_quotation->getstatus()` returns the strings "Active" or "Expired" before internationalization, just add something like this to the condition that displays the link:

```
 <td><?php echo $this->__($_quotation->getstatus()); ?></td>
 <td class="a-center">
     <?php if ($_quotation->isViewableByCustomer() && ($_quotation->getstatus() == "Active" || $_quotation->getstatus() == "Expired")): ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $this->getViewUrl($_quotation) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Quotation') ?></a>
     <?php endif; ?>
 </td>
```

**EDIT** According to comment below, `isViewableByCustomer()` is not relevant here, so try:

```
 <td><?php echo $this->__($_quotation->getstatus()); ?></td>
 <td class="a-center">
     <?php if ($_quotation->getstatus() == "Active" || $_quotation->getstatus() == "Expired"): ?>
          <a href="<?php echo $this->getViewUrl($_quotation) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Quotation') ?></a>
     <?php endif; ?>
 </td>
```

Comment: This works with active and also doesn't show pending which is great but the expired link still doesn't show

Comment: @Vince Pettit Then it's possible that `getstatus()` doesn't return _exactly_ the string "Expired", but rather that string "Expired" is derived after internationalization `__()`.  Find out exactly what `getstatus()` returns.

Comment: We've come across the following:  const STATUS_NEW = 'New';  const STATUS_CUSTOMER_REQUEST = 'Pending';  const STATUS_ACTIVE = 'Active';  const STATUS_EXPIRED = 'Expired';

Comment: @Vince Pettit Somewhere where you can read the result on an expired record, just `echo $_quotation->getstatus();`.  Also are you certain that `isViewableByCustomer()` is `TRUE` for expired records?  If it is false, then the other side of the `&&` won't be evaluated.

Comment: Just realised the isViewableByCustomer() will only give a true value on Active. This function can be dropped from the code. We need it to display the link on a value from echo $_quotation->getstatus();

Comment: @Vince Pettit Please see the edit above omitting `isViewableByCustomer()` and accept if ti works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php if ($this->__($_quotation->getstatus() == "Active" || $this->__($_quotation->getstatus() == "Expired"){?><td><?php echo $this->__($_quotation->getstatus()); ?></td>
        <td class="a-center">
            <?php if ($_quotation->isViewableByCustomer()): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getViewUrl($_quotation) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Quotation') ?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
```